# Trying to convert a jQuery plugin to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a jQuery plugin that I want to convert into pure javascript, so that I can drop the dependency on jQuery. The part of the plugin i'm stuck on is this bit, which returns the DOM elements sorted by depth (eg. body's children, then grandchildren, then great-grand-children, etc etc)

```
var first = $('body'),
output = [];
while(first.length != 0) {
  output = $.merge(output, first);
  first = first.children();
}
```

basically I just need the pure javascript version of `$('body')` , `$.merge` and `children()` to help me on my way.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you give (edit your question) a few examples of how you would like to use these functions (pretend they exist and work)?  Sorted by depth, well, the children, then grandchildren,... makes up a family tree; not just a sorted list.  Please explain what you expect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return an array of all the DOM elements, sorted by depth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537427/return-an-array-of-all-the-dom-elements-sorted-by-depth)

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay The op has a duplicate question they posted yesterday that has a better explanation and example of what they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself, it was pretty simple in the end.

```
    // Every Element in the DOM.

var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),

    // All the Element's children sorted by depth, 
    // ie. body, then body's children, grandchildren,
    // so on and so forth.

    sortedByDepth = [];

    // for every element

for(var i = 0; i<allElements.length; ++i) {

    // grab Its children

    var allChildren = allElements[i].children;

    // for every grabbed child

    for(var j = 0; j<allChildren.length; ++j){

        // Add it to the sortedByDepth array

        sortedByDepth = sortedByDepth.concat(allChildren[j]);
    }   
}
console.log(sortedByDepth);
```